# Testing surrounding try catch method with mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito

Im figuring out, how to test this method and force the exception "DataAccessResourceFailureException", but i didn't have a valid way to do it.

I need to force that exception at "ProductRepositoryImpl" class. Any ideas?

ProductRepositoryImpl

```
  @Override
  public Product saveProduct(Product input) {
  try {
    return productRepositoryAdapter.saveProduct(input);
  } catch (DataAccessResourceFailureException e) {
    logger.error(ERROR_WHEN_SAVING_PRODUCT_DATA_DETAIL + e.getMessage());
  }
    return null;
  }
```

ProductRepositoryAdapter

```
  public Product saveProduct(Product input) throws DataAccessResourceFailureException {
    ProductData productData = UtilTransform.productToProductData(input);

    // This method throws exception when there's no connection
    Product createdProduct = productDataRepository.findSkuByCountry(input.getSku(), 
    input.getCountry());

    if (createdProduct == null) {
       return Product.fromModel(productDataRepository.save(productData));
    } else {
      logger.error(THE_PRODUCT_ALREADY_EXISTS_IN_THE_RECORDS);
    }
      return null;
  }
```

ProductDataRepository

```
public interface ProductDataRepository extends MongoRepository<ProductData, String> {

  @Query("{'sku': ?0, 'country': ?1}")
  public Product findSkuByCountry(String sku, String country);

  public Optional<ProductData> findById(ProductId id);
}
```

And my Test, Im using mockito.

```
@Test
void saveProductException() {
  Mockito.when(productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct())).thenReturn(buildProduct());
  Mockito.when(adapter.saveProduct(buildProduct())).
      thenThrow(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class);

  Assertions.assertThrows(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class, 
  () -> productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct()));
}
```

Error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

---

EDIT.

I change a little bit my approach, with this code (thanks guys) i was able to throw the exception so my code it will return null. After that checking my jacoco index.html i can see that "exception" its covered successfully.

```
  @Test
  void saveProductException() {
    Product product = buildProduct();
    Mockito.when(adapter.saveProduct(product)).
       thenThrow(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class);
   Assertions.assertNull(productRepository.saveProduct(product));
  }
```

Comment: make sure you have equals overriden on `Product` class

Comment: The function you are testing does not throw as the exception is catched. It just returns null. `assertThat(productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct())).isNull();`

Comment: @NicoVanBelle Could be, but there's always the possibility that one of the methods called by `saveProduct` throws that exception and it bubbles up.

Comment: @xtratic unless `logger.error` starts throwing `DataAccessResourceFailureException` which I doubt, there is no exception of that type ever coming out of `ProductRepository#saveProduct`. FYI I'm NOT downvoting anyone..

Comment: @NicoVanBelle But OP is also defining `Mockito.when(productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct())).thenReturn(buildProduct());` so shouldn't `saveProduct` be returning `buildProduct()` regardless?

Comment: @xtratic I missed that part. But then again he's never going to see that exception boiling up as adapter won't be called.

Comment: What class are you even trying to test here? If it is the repository, you can't mock it.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle Yep, exactly the point of my answer below, if you think it's correct then upvotes would be helpful.

Comment: As a sidenote; I would bind the result of buildProduct() to a variable and re-use that object so you are sure it will match across all mock configurations

Comment: @daniu im try to test my "ProductRepositoryImpl" the var its called "productRepository" it can be a little confusing.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle yep, sometimes use a method like this (buildProduct()) its not the best way, in another test i used any(Product.class) instead. anyways im trying several options now.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle thanks mate !! it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems suspect:

```
Mockito.when(   productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct())   ).thenReturn(buildProduct());
. . .
Assertions.assertThrows(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class, 
        () ->   productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct())   );
```

You're saying, when `productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct())` is called then return `buildProduct()` but then you assert that when it's called it should throw `DataAccessResourceFailureException`?

Instead maybe try this:

```
@Test
void saveProductException() {
    // as NicoVanBelle recommends, ensure you're referencing the same product throughout this test
    Product product = buildProduct();
    Mockito.when(adapter.saveProduct(product).thenThrow(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class);

    // Also as NicoVanBelle points out, when your `adapter` throws, `saveProduct` will return `null`
    Assertions.assertThat(productRepository.saveProduct(product)).isNull();
}
```

Comment: thanks !! to you and @NicoVanBelle, finnally with this code i was be able to throw the exception and get it with "assertNull" because, if there's a exception in my code, then it'll return null.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect 2 things here

1. You have setup the `productRepository.saveProduct` to not to throw and then you assert it throw the exception

`Assertions.assertThrows(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class,  () -> productRepository.saveProduct(buildProduct()));`

2. You are calling `buildProduct()` which I assume returns the new product but mockito tries to check the argument equality so takeout it as `Product myProduct = buildProduct()` and use `myProduct`

```
@Test
void saveProductException() {
  Product myProduct = buildProduct();
  
    Mockito.when(productRepository.saveProduct(myProduct))
          .thenThrow(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class);;
  
    Mockito.when(adapter.saveProduct(buildProduct())).
      thenThrow(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class);

    Assertions.assertThrows(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class, 
         () -> productRepository.saveProduct(myProduct));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! i tested but i have a few problems yet. now i figured out how to solve it (i updated the main thread) anyways thanks for your time @Pavan !!